# Finding the limit to the power of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that n $\in{N}$ and $a_n$ $\ne 0$. Assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.   Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+a_n)^{1/a_n}=e$.

Really having a tough time with this one. Can anyone help? This question is in the subsequential limit problem section.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rewrite
$$(1+a_n)^{1/a_n}=e^{\frac{1}{a_n}\ln(1+a_n)}$$
and compute  the limit of the exponent using Taylor polynomials or the definition of the derivative of $\ln$.